# Full screen caller for Android

Tags: android

I would like to developed full screen caller application in android.

How can i add my activity on top of the call screen of my phone? Any example?

Answer (score 6):

i dont really understand your question, but a fullscreen view can be created by the following code:

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

note: its important to call this before setContentView();

Comment: Thanks for reply. but i want when some one is calling me than i want fullscreen photo of that caller to be appeared in my screen means fullscreen caller id.so how can i place full screen photo at top of the incoming screen.. any example..?